# Equal to check working only on first column in postgres

Tags: postgresql

I am facing a strange problem while using postgresql. I have a table with columns as `id`, `data`, `day_data`. I am firing a simple query

```
select * from tablename where id = 'someid';
```

However, when I am modifying the query to

```
select * from tablename where day_data = 'somedata';
```

Both the columns are primary key of the table and both have a data type of chracter varying (255). This, is a very strange behavior and I am not able to make any head or tail out of it. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You haven't said what the error is, what the problem is, and you haven't shown any sample data. or output.

Comment: There is no error it's just that no rows are being selected. This is basically the data in my table .

Comment: WHAT is basically the data in your table?

Comment: There is no error it's just that no rows are being selected. This is basically the data in my table .  

id data day_data
abc count1 day1
bcd count2 day2

Now when i fire query select * from tablename where id ='abc', i get the result

abc count1 day1

but when i fire query select * from tablename where day_data='day1', no rows get selected

Comment: Try `SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE TRIM(day_data) = 'day1';` and tell us if you get a different result.

Comment: Yes TRIM(day_data) works :). Thanks a lot. Can you please elaborate as to what was the issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that you've got trailing spaces in your data values. `TRIM()` removes trailing whitespace. One way to find out would be `SELECT '"' || day_data || '"' FROM tablename;`, which will enclose each value *including leading and trailing whitespace* with quotes.

Comment: Yes, that precisely seems to be the issue. The data was imported from a previous nosql database and there are multiple white spaces.